# Get multiple request params of the same name

Tags: python, flask

My problem is that with the given code:

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return str(request.values.get("param", "None"))

app.run(debug=True)
```

and I visit:

```
http://localhost:5000/?param=a&param=bbb
```

I should expect an output of ['a', 'bbb'] except Flask seems to only accept the first param and ignore the rest.

Is this a limitation of Flask? Or is it by design?

Answer (score 110, accepted):

You can use `getlist`, which is similar to Django's `getList` but for some reason isn't mentioned in the Flask documentation:

```
return str(request.args.getlist('param'))
```

The result is:

```
[u'a', u'bbb']
```

Use `request.args` if the param is in the query string (as in the question), `request.form` if the values come from multiple form inputs with the same name.  `request.values` combines both, but should normally be avoided for the more specific collection.

Comment: `request.values` is an instance of `CombinedMultiDict`, a subclass of `MultiDict`, which is part of Werkzeug. `getlist()` method is described in its docs: http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict.getlist

Answer (score 4):

If you used `$('form').serialize()` in jQuery to encode your form data, you can use `request.form['name']` to get data, but note that when multiple input elements' names are the same, `request.form['name']` will only get the first matched item.  So I checked the form object from the Flask API, and I found [this](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/api/#flask.Request.form).  Then I checked the [MultiDict object](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict), and I found the function `getlist('name')`.

If there are multiple inputs with the same name, try this method: `request.form.getlist('name')`

Comment: this worked perfectly, except its actually `request.form.getlist('list_name')`. change the brackets please.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use a flat json structure with request.args. Because sometimes you simply do not know the parameter beforehand and you cannot use `.getlist()`.

```
arguments = request.args.to_dict(flat=False)

# Get a specific parameter
param = arguments.get('param')
print(param)

# Get all the parameters that have more than one value
for field, values in arguments.items():
    if len(values) > 1:
        print(values)
```

Answer (score -5):

> One more way is that you can use one key and one value that holds multiple values and then in the server you can split and do what ever you want .Hope this Helps somewone

```
http://localhost/api/products/filters?Manufacturer=Dell|HP|HUAWEI|Lenovo
```

#### OR

```
http://localhost/api/products/filters?Manufacturer=Dell_HP_HUAWEI_Lenovo
```

#### OR

```
http://localhost/api/products/filters?Manufacturer=Dell__HP__HUAWEI__Lenovo
```