# How to send large amounts of HTML form input to Flask?

Tags: javascript, python, html, forms, flask

I have an HTML form where users can add an unlimited amount of a pair of text fields. I have used some Javascript so that each new text input has a Div surrounding it with a unique ID to identify each text field separately. Like this:

```
<div id="1">
<textarea name="firstTextArea"></textarea>
<textarea name="secondTextArea"></textarea>
</div>

<div id="2">
<textarea name="firstTextArea"></textarea>
<textarea name="secondTextArea"></textarea>
</div>

<div id="3">
<textarea name="firstTextArea"></textarea>
<textarea name="secondTextArea"></textarea>
</div>
```

and so forth.

How can I request this data from the form into Flask? It would be easy if there was a fixed number of inputs but the number of inputs will vary depending on what the user chooses.

One way I have thought of doing this is to count the number of input fields of the HTML form though I'm not sure how to count it using Javascript and then sending/requesting it to Flask along with the text field data.

What would be the best way to go about this?

Comment: Are you just asking how to get multiple params of the same name? See answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14188451/python-flask-multiple-request-params-of-the-same-name.  Your parameter pairs should be ordered the same way, so firstTextArea[0] should correspond to secondTextArea[0]

Comment: @Spencer But then how would I do that for each textarea and know when to stop at the last textarea?

Comment: When you are checking the parameter values, you will be getting an array back. You simply loop through them until you get to the end.

Comment: @Spencer How will I be able to get Flask to know when to get to the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to solve this issue using this code:

```
firstTextArea = []
secondTextArea = []
x = 1
while True:
    try:
        firstTextArea.append(request.form['firstTextArea' + str(x)])
        secondTextArea.append(request.form['secondTextArea' + str(x)])
    except:
        break
    x += 1
```

Instead of naming the DIVs, I uniquely named each textarea, so that I can identify them in the code above.